# Custom Keyboard and default keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-keypad, android-input-method

Ok so I have a custom keyboard view that opens on touch event on a edit text but when i use it on a device the default keyboard shows and it overlaps my custom keyboard so i have to click back button for the default keyboard to go down and for my custom keyboard to actually show on screen. I have tried Inputmethodmanager method to hide default keyboard implicitly. It hides on the emulator when i enable physical keyboard input but not on a full touch device. Please help me out.